# Load Test Express APIs (nodejs) using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, passport.js

I am trying to load test Express Apis (nodejs) using **Jmeter**.
I am using passport to login.
I am able to login using JMeter but when I make another request which needs authorisation I am getting an error. I have a middleware to check authorisation where I am checking '**req.user**'. But when using Jmeter **req.user** is ***undefined***.

Can anyone tell me what am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks 
:)

Comment: I suggest recording the script using `Test Script Recorder`, which records HTTP requests. Then, add `HTTP Cookie Manger` config element. If still not working, then you MUST correlate the dynamic values by capturing them from responses using `Regular Expression Extractor` and send.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Creating a Simple Node/Express API Authentication System with Passport and JWT](http://blog.slatepeak.com/creating-a-simple-node-express-api-authentication-system-with-passport-and-jwt/) article you are missing [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) - handling the dynamic authentication token, you need to do the following to work this around:

1. Send a [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to `/authenticate` endpoint
2. Extract the `token` using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
3. Add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to the next HTTP Request and configure it to send `Authorization` header with the value of the token, extracted in step 2.

Comment: But I am not using any JWT